# SortBy behaving strangely with missing data

Tags: sorting

I'm trying to create a grid that shows the largest data value from a list.

What I have *mostly* works- the problem comes when there is missing data.

[image: img1]

You can't really tell here, but all of the missing data is at the bottom.

[image: img2]

Here you can see all the missing data is at the top...

I'm using `SortBy` to handle the sorting, and just can't seem to get the function to work. For instance, this works just like you'd expect:

```
SortBy[ finalData, { #[[2]] } &]
```

However, this does not:

```
SortBy[ finalData, { Function[ #[[2]] ] } &]
```

It also doesn't work when you throw in a `Return` either.

I've tried to extend that to a conditional `If[ NumberQ[ ... ], #[[2]]` and so forth, but if I can't get the most basic example working, I obviously can't the more complicated one working.

Code, for reference:

```
(* Utility functions *)
removeMissingData[ data_ ] := 
 DeleteCases[ data, _?( ! FreeQ[ #, _Missing ] & ) ]

divideStatsData[ data1_, data2_ ] := ( 
  Module[ { data }, (* Module makes declared variables local *)
   data = { #, CountryData[ #, data1 ], CountryData[ #, data2 ] } & /@ 
     CountryData[];
   (* Missing data / missing data = 1 *)
   data = removeMissingData[ data ];
   { #[[1]], #[[2]] / #[[3]] } & /@ data
   ] 
  )

extractData[ data_ ] := 
 QuantityMagnitude @ Flatten[ Transpose[ data ][[ 2 ]] ]

drawMapWithTooltips[ data_ ] := ( Module[ { rawData, min, max },
   rawData = extractData[ data ];
   { min, max } = { Min[ rawData ], Max[ rawData ] };
   GeoRegionValuePlot[ 
    data,  
    PlotRange -> { min, max },
    GeoLabels -> ( 
      Tooltip[ 
        #1, (* Location *)
        Extract[ 
         Extract[  (* First extract removes ugly braces, 
          second actually gets information *)
          data, 
          Position[ data, #2, 2 ] + { { 0, 1 } } (* 
          Search through table by country (#2) *)
          (* Could just recalculate the value again... *)
          ], 1 ]
        ] &
      )
    ]
   ] 
  )

sortFromGreatestToLeast[ data_ ] := Sort[ data, #1[[2]] > #2[[2]] &]

arableLandPerPopulation = divideStatsData[ "ArableLandArea", "Population" ];
drawMapWithTooltips[ arableLandPerPopulation ]

currentAccountBalancePerGDP = divideStatsData[ "CurrentAccountBalance", "GDP" ];
drawMapWithTooltips[ currentAccountBalancePerGDP ]

governmentSurplusPerGDP = divideStatsData[ "GovernmentSurplus", "GDP" ];
drawMapWithTooltips[ governmentSurplusPerGDP ]

governmentDebtPerGDP = divideStatsData[ "GovernmentDebt", "GDP" ];
drawMapWithTooltips[ governmentDebtPerGDP ]

militaryExpenditurePerPopulation = divideStatsData[ "MilitaryExpenditures", "Population" ];
drawMapWithTooltips[ militaryExpenditurePerPopulation ]

militaryExpenditurePerGovernmentDebt = divideStatsData[ "MilitaryExpenditures", "GovernmentDebt" ];
drawMapWithTooltips[ militaryExpenditurePerGovernmentDebt ]


combine[ data_, names_ ] := (
  countries = CountryData[];
  return = { Join[ { "Country" }, names ] };
  statsFinal = {};
  For[ i = 1, i <= Length[ data ], i++,
   new = { # };
   stats = ( 
       temp = Position[ data[[ i ]], # ]; 
       temp = If[ 
         Length[ temp ] > 0, 
         Extract[ Extract[ data[[ i ]], temp + {{ 0, 1 }} ], 1 ], 
         Missing["NotAvailable"]
         ];
       temp
       ) & /@ CountryData[];
   AppendTo[ statsFinal, stats ];
   ];
  For[ i = 1, i <= Length[ CountryData[] ], i++,
   new = { CountryData[ countries[[i]], "Name" ] };
   For[ ii = 1, ii <= Length[ statsFinal ], ii++,
    AppendTo[ new, statsFinal[[ii]][[i]] ]
    ];
   AppendTo[ return, new ];
   ];
  return
  )

finalData = combine[ 
   { militaryExpenditurePerGovernmentDebt, 
    militaryExpenditurePerPopulation, governmentDebtPerGDP, 
    governmentSurplusPerGDP, currentAccountBalancePerGDP, 
    arableLandPerPopulation },
   { "militaryExpenditurePerGovernmentDebt", 
    "militaryExpenditurePerPopulation", "governmentDebtPerGDP", 
    "governmentSurplusPerGDP", "currentAccountBalancePerGDP", 
    "arableLandPerPopulation" } 
   ];

    Manipulate[ 
 Grid[ 
  Reverse[
   Join[
    SortBy[ 
     Take[ finalData, { 2, Length[ finalData ] } ], 
     Function[ x, 
      x[[ Extract[Extract[Position[finalData[[1]], top], 1], 1] ]] ]
     ],
    Take[ finalData, 1 ]
    ]
   ],
  Frame -> All
  ], {
  top, {
   "militaryExpenditurePerGovernmentDebt", 
   "militaryExpenditurePerPopulation", 
   "governmentDebtPerGDP", 
   "governmentSurplusPerGDP", 
   "currentAccountBalancePerGDP", 
   "arableLandPerPopulation"
   } }
 ]
```

So I guess the question is really: How can I organize columns of data with missing data involved?

Comment: What behavior would be acceptable to you regarding your missing data? Where should they end up?

Comment: Also, what does `divideStatsData` do in your code? Its definition is missing.

Comment: @MarcoB Acceptable behavior would be to put them at the bottom. Sorry about missing some of the code, should be in there now.

Comment: `SortBy[ finalData, { Function[ #[[2]] } &]` has no closing square bracket and mixes syntax. Try `SortBy[ finalData, #[[2]]&]` or `SortBy[ finalData,Function[x, x[[2]]]]`

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch Sorry, typed it in wrong. I tried your suggested function and it still puts `Missing[NotAvailable]` on top when I select `governmentSurplusPerGDP`.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could put some representative small test sample of your data that could be copied and pasted.

Comment: @JackLaVigne Sorry, I should have thought of that... loading all that data is a lot to ask. I'll keep that in mind next time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
NA = Missing["NotAvailable"];
SM = 10^-9.;
```

The situation arises when you make a reverse sort like this one

```
data = {{"Libya", 1, 2, NA, 3}, {"Belgium", NA, 10, 30 , 20}, {"Egypt", NA, NA, 8, 7}, {"USA", 21, 18, 18, 17}};

Reverse @ SortBy[data, #[[2]] &] // TableForm
```

[image]

Solution: Temporarily replace missing data with a number small enough to not occur in your data.

```
Reverse @ SortBy[data /. NA :> SM, #[[2]] &] /. SM :> NA // TableForm
```

[image]

Comment: Worked like a charm! (Expect an upvote once I have the rep)... only modification was I changed `SM` to `-10^-9.`, because I had some negative data as well.

Answer (score 3):

Using eldo's example `data`:

```
data = {{"Libya", 1, 2, NA, 3}, {"Belgium", NA, 10, 30, 20}, 
  {"Egypt", NA, NA, 8, 7}, {"USA", 21, 18, 18, 17}};

ReverseSortBy[{#[[2]] &} /* DeleteCases[NA]] @ data // TableForm
```

[image]