# Sorting with Missing values

Tags: associations, sorting

I have the following data:

```
dt =
  <|"Austria" -> <|"2018" -> 3848, "2019" -> 3965, "2020" -> 4099, "2021" -> 4662|>,
   "Belgium" -> <|"2018" -> 3731, "2019" -> 3838, "2020" -> 3861, "2021" -> 4167|>,
   "Denmark" -> <|"2018" -> 3701, "2019" -> 3796, "2020" -> Missing[_], "2021"-> Missing[_]|>,
   "Finland" -> <|"2018" -> 3020, "2019" -> 3105, "2020" -> 3205, "2021" -> Missing[_]|>,
   "Sweden" -> <|"2018" -> Missing[_], "2019" -> 3830, "2020" -> 3919,"2021" -> 4200|>,
   "Estonia" -> <|"2018" -> 4834, "2019" -> 4917, "2020" -> 4997, "2021" -> Missing[_]|>|>;
```

`ReverseSort` by the last two years:

```
ReverseSortBy[dt, {Key["2021"], Key["2020"]}] // Dataset
```

[image]

Unfortunately, the missing values are placed in front of the others,
and I could not find a `Sort` - specification to correct that. The
solution I found is too complicated:

```
 move[in_, yr_] :=
     Module[{dt, mi},
      dt = ReverseSort @ Query[All, {yr}] @ in;
      mi = MatchQ[#, KeyValuePattern[_ -> Missing[_]]] & /@ dt;
      mi = Keys @ Select[Normal @ mi, Last];
      <|KeyDrop[dt, mi], KeyTake[dt, mi]|>]


a = move[dt, #] & /@ {"2021", "2020"};
b = Query[All, {"2018", "2019"}] @ dt;
```

The expected result:

```
KeySort /@ Merge[{a, b}, Association] // Dataset
```

[image]

Better / shorter ways to do this?

Comment: Didn't you yourself provide an [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/99551/75628) a few years ago? :)

Comment: OMG. I also just find it now

Comment: Oops, shame on me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ReverseSortBy[dt, DeleteMissing@{#"2021", #"2020"} &] // Dataset
```

[image]

Alternatively,

```
ReverseSortBy[dt, {#"2021", #"2020"} & /* DeleteMissing] // Dataset
```

> same result

Comment: More elegant solution 

Comment: Excellent - but why does it function?

Comment: @eldo, _`SortBy[e,f]`  is equivalent to `Sort[{f[#],#}&/@e][[All,-1]]`_ ([SortBy --  Properties and Relations](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SortBy.html)). So `ReverseSortBy[dt, {#"2021", #"2020"} &/*DeleteMissing]` is actually doing the same thing as `dt[[Reverse@Ordering@Map[DeleteMissing@{#"2021", #"2020"} &]@dt]]`

Comment: If I replace 2020 with 2018, it seems that I can't obtain a reasonable result.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [trick](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/99550/sortby-behaving-strangely-with-missing-data) , we can temporarily replace missing data with a number small enough to not occur in your data. Then recover it after sort operation.

```
NA = Missing[_];
SM = 10^-9.;
ReverseSortBy[
   dt /. NA -> SM, {Key["2021"], Key["2020"]}] /. {SM -> 
    NA} // Dataset
```